# Linear equation uncertainty

Tags: linear-algebra

For example: Solve the linear equation $2x-3=0$ for $x$. If one would divide both sides by 2 to remove the factor 2 from x, would he have to divide the 2x and the -3 by 2 or only the 2x part?

Comment: Both. $2x-3=2(x-\frac32)$

Comment: Got it. So anytime a linear equation needs to be solved I have to treat every side as one entity? So if one would divide both sides by 2 it would look like (2x-3)/2=0/2?

Comment: Correct. If you run into difficulties, just try a test case with numbers

Comment: Even people knowing this rule occasionally forget to divide all the terms. This common mistake can be avoided in the case of linear equations by seperating first. And anyway , many mistakes can be avoided by verifying the solution , no matter how easy the exercise is , assuming we got a unique solution.